# Can you edit Tetris in Python so that you do not have to repeatedly have to press the arrow keys to move the object?

Tags: python, tetris

I am trying to make Tetris in python using pygame but so far I have to keep repeatedly pressing the arrow keys for the pieces to move. I was wondering if you could just keep holding the arrow keys to move the pieces.
Here is the link to my code (It is on PasteBin
https://pastebin.com/wJ93gcUw
Here is the first few lines of my code (It was too long to post so I put it on Pastebin.)

```
import pygame
import random

"""
10 x 20 square grid
shapes: S, Z, I, O, J, L, T
represented in order by 0 - 6
"""

pygame.font.init()

# GLOBALS VARS
s_width = 800
s_height = 700
play_width = 300  # meaning 300 // 10 = 30 width per block
play_height = 600  # meaning 600 // 20 = 20 height per blo ck
block_size = 30

top_left_x = (s_width - play_width) // 2
top_left_y = s_height - play_height


# SHAPE FORMATS

S = [['.....',
      '.....',
      '..00.',
      '.00..',
      '.....'],
     ['.....',
      '..0..',
      '..00.',
      '...0.',
      '.....']]

Z = [['.....',
      '.....',
      '.00..',
      '..00.',
      '.....'],
     ['.....',
      '..0..',
      '.00..',
      '.0...',
      '.....']]

I = [['..0..',
      '..0..',
      '..0..',
      '..0..',
      '.....'],
     ['.....',
      '0000.',
      '.....',
      '.....',
      '.....']]

O = [['.....',
      '.....',
      '.00..',
      '.00..',
      '.....']]

J = [['.....',
      '.0...',
      '.000.',
      '.....',
      '.....'],
     ['.....',
      '..00.',
      '..0..',
      '..0..',
      '.....'],
     ['.....',
      '.....',
      '.000.',
      '...0.',
      '.....'],
     ['.....',
      '..0..',
      '..0..',
      '.00..',
      '.....']]

L = [['.....',
      '...0.',
      '.000.',
      '.....',
      '.....'],
     ['.....',
      '..0..',
      '..0..',
      '..00.',
      '.....'],
     ['.....',
      '.....',
      '.000.',
      '.0...',
      '.....'],
     ['.....',
      '.00..',
      '..0..',
      '..0..',
      '.....']]

T = [['.....',
      '..0..',
      '.000.',
      '.....',
      '.....'],
     ['.....',
      '..0..',
      '..00.',
      '..0..',
      '.....'],
     ['.....',
      '.....',
      '.000.',
      '..0..',
      '.....'],
     ['.....',
      '..0..',
      '.00..',
      '..0..',
      '.....']]

shapes = [S, Z, I, O, J, L, T]
shape_colors = [(0, 255, 0), (255, 0, 0), (0, 255, 255), (255, 255, 0), (255, 165, 0), (0, 0, 255), (128, 0, 128)]
# index 0 - 6 represent shape
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pygame.key.get_pressed](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) to do that.

For example, to get the continuous input of the Up or Down keys:

```
while running:
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()  #checking pressed keys
if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
    y1 -= 1
if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
    y1 += 1
```

Comment: I used the website, thanks for the link! This helped me a lot as now I can post it like real Tetris. :-)